# How to give column list for select statement in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

below code is for select "country", "gender" from "Message" where ~

```
    users = session.query(
        Message.country,
        Message.gender,
    ).filter(
        Message.date_joined.between(begin_date, end_date),
    ).all()
```

when I try sql with this

```
    columns = (
        Message.country,
        Message.gender,
    )

    users = session.query(
        columns
    ).filter(
        Message.date_joined.between(begin_date, end_date),
    ).all()
```

I got error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '(<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x117f215c8>, <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x117f21518>)'
```

I thought if i gave parameter as tuple, would be possible however there was exception.

How can I give columns as variable for query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

columns should be a part of a list and use load_only

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import load_only
columns = ['country', 'gender']

companies = session.query(Message).options(load_only(*columns)).filter(
             Message.date_joined.between(begin_date, end_date)).all()
```

You can also try with_entities

```
columns = [Message.country, Message.gender]
companies = session.query(Message).filter(
                 Message.date_joined.between(begin_date, end_date)).with_entities(*columns).all()
```

Comment: I still got this exception with your solution. sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '[<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x10af3b5c8>, <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x10af3b518>]'

Comment: columns = [
        UserLastMessage.country,
        UserLastMessage.gender
    ]

    user_profile = session.query(
        columns
    ).filter(
        UserLastMessage.date_joined.between(begin_date, end_date)
    ).all()

Comment: I have updated the answer. It is expecting the entity to query.

Comment: Just `session.query(*columns)...` would do as well, given the original tuple of attributes.